# Move second line to end of third line // notepad++

Tags: excel, notepad++, vba

I have the following txt-file containing a block of three lines and repeating (4000 lines total):

```
Printer1
/900
HBA/8/7
Printer2
/800
HBA/7/2
```

Now I would like to move the second line to the end of the third line and then repeat (5th line to end of 6th; 8th line to end of 9th and so on)

Any chance this can be done with notepad++? Or maybe Excel macro? I found some examples with regex and vmi but the problem is they were looking for keywords. I would just like to have the whole 2nd line moved to end of 3rd... and then continue the pattern (5th->6th; 8th->9th)

Any input/idea/solution is deeply appreciated.

Kind regards

Mitch

Answer (score 0):

Alright, sometimes a bit of time brings ideas :)

I just imported the txt-file in Excel so row 1 is "Printer1" and row 2 is "/900" and so on.
Then I just made like this:

```
B1 =A1
B2 =A3&A2
B3 =empty
```

Then i just marked B1 to B3 and dragged it with pressed ctrl key until the end of the file. Et voilà I have what i need. Now i just will copy column B to new txt-file and everything is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+\R\K(.+\R)(.+\R)`
- Replace with: `$2$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
  .+        : 1 or more any character but newline (ie. the first line)
  \K        : forget all we have seen until this position
  (.+\R)    : Group 1, 1 or more any character followed by linebreak (ie. the second line)
  (.+\R)    : Group 2, 1 or more any character followed by linebreak (ie. the third line)
```

**Replacement:**

```
$2      : content of group 2
$1      : content of group 1
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Printer1
HBA/8/7
/900
Printer2
HBA/7/2
/800
```